# keyDown: is not responding even though the class it is implemented in acceptsFirstResponder

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsresponder

I have made my NSView in my application.

```
 - (BOOL) acceptsFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}
```

Now my implemented keyDown: doesnt respond... the breakpoint or NSBeep(); I have implemented dont fire.

My implmented mouseDown in that same class works fine...

Ideas why my keyDown is not responding?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it actually becomes the first responder?

Comment: An easy way to make sure is to implement `-becomeFirstResponder` and `resignFirstResponder` and make a change to the view when it has first responder status.